# EF Core Sqlite one-to-many, adding a new record

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core, blazor-webassembly

I am working on a project that has a relationship near enough to the one in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships

```
public class Blog
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = $"Blog-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post>? Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public string Id { get; set; } = $"Post-{Guid.NewGuid()}";
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public required Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

When I want to add a new post to the database, I have a form where the author would select the blog they are posting to from a dropdown and then make the new post.

What I have done so far to avoid getting an error for unique constraints related to the Blog object is this:

```
public void AddPost(Post newPost)
{
    var blog = _context.Blogs
                       .Include(b => b.Posts)
                       .FirstOrDefault(b => b.Id == newPost.Blog.Id);

    blog.Posts ??= new List<Post>();
    blog.Posts.Add(newPost);

    _context.Blogs.Update(blog);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Is it possible to avoid getting the blog from the `Blogs` table before just inserting the `newPost` into the `Posts` table? I initially thought if I had added the new post, EF Core would just add that post to the related `Blog` object, but instead it tries to make the blog again in the `Blog` table, thus giving a unique constraint error.

So the question is, is this the way this should be done, or is there a better way?

Comment: Is there a `_context.Posts` property?

Comment: yes the context has both DbSet<Blog> Blogs; and DbSet<Post> Posts;

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach of loading the Blog from the database and then adding the new Post to it is a valid and common way to handle this situation. It ensures that you have a valid reference to the Blog entity that the new Post should belong to and correctly establishes the relationship.

However, if you want to avoid loading the Blog from the database explicitly, you can do the following:

1. Create a detached Blog entity and set its Id property to match the Blog Id in the newPost object.
2. Attach the detached Blog entity to the context or set its state to Unchanged.
3. Add the newPost to the context.

Here's an example of how you can modify your AddPost method to achieve this:

```
public void AddPost(Post newPost)
{
    var blog = new Blog { Id = newPost.Blog.Id }; // Create a detached Blog with the same Id

    // Attach the detached Blog entity to the context, marking it as Unchanged
    _context.Attach(blog);

    // Add the new Post to the context
    _context.Add(newPost);

    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Reminder: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Stack Overflow